# how to trigger appropriate xaml page with button

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

i'm using example take from project "japf_fr_slide_animation". i've added button to trigger appropriate page but is stuck and dont know how to trigger them. Here are all the pages to the referenced project with the added buttons. Can anyone help on how I can trigger the pages based on the button?

view1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstTry.view1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="view1" />
        <Button Name="show2" Content="show second xaml" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

view2.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstTry.view2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightCoral">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="view2"/>
        <Button Name="show3" Content="show third xaml" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

view3.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstTry.view3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightGreen">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="view3"/>
        <Button Name="show1" Content="show first xaml" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FirstTry.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="views">
            <x:XData>
                <Views xmlns="">
                    <View Title="View1">
                        <Page Source="view1.xaml"/> 
                    </View>
                    <View Title="View2">
                        <Page Source="view2.xaml"/>
                    </View>
                    <View Title="View3">
                        <Page Source="view3.xaml"/>
                    </View>
                </Views>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>

        <Storyboard x:Key="slideLeftToRight"  
                    TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                    AccelerationRatio=".4"
                    DecelerationRatio=".4">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="viewer" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="300" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bordervisual" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="0" To="-300"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="slideRightToLeft" 
                    TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                    AccelerationRatio=".4"
                    DecelerationRatio=".4">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="viewer" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="-300" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bordervisual" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="0" To="300"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <VisualBrush x:Key="VisualBrush1" Visual="{Binding ElementName=viewer}"/>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ListBox x:Name="viewList" Height="20" Width="300" SelectedIndex="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource views}, XPath=Views/View}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="@Title"                    
                    SelectionChanged="viewList_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid Width="300" Height="300">



                <Border x:Name="bordervisual" Width="300">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectanglevisual"/>
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>

                <ItemsControl x:Name="viewer" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=viewList}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Page}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame x:Name="frame" Source="{Binding XPath=@Source}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private static int oldSelectedIndex = 0;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public RenderTargetBitmap RenderBitmap(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            double topLeft = 0;
            double topRight = 0;
            int width = (int)element.ActualWidth;
            int height = (int)element.ActualHeight;
            double dpiX = 96; // this is the magic number
            double dpiY = 96; // this is the magic number

            PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
            VisualBrush elementBrush = new VisualBrush(element);
            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen();

            dc.DrawRectangle(elementBrush, null, new Rect(topLeft, topRight, width, height));
            dc.Close();

            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, pixelFormat);

            bitmap.Render(visual);
            return bitmap;
        } 

        private void viewList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlElement root = (XmlElement)viewer.DataContext;
            XmlNodeList xnl = root.SelectNodes("Page");

            if (viewer.ActualHeight > 0 && viewer.ActualWidth > 0)
            {
                RenderTargetBitmap rtb = RenderBitmap(viewer);
                rectanglevisual.Fill = new ImageBrush(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
            }

            viewer.ItemsSource = xnl;

            if (oldSelectedIndex < viewList.SelectedIndex)
            {
                viewer.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.Resources["slideLeftToRight"]);
            }
            else
            {
                viewer.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.Resources["slideRightToLeft"]);
            }

            oldSelectedIndex = viewList.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty simple way to do this, would be to have a command fire from each of the buttons, whenever they are being clicked. The new page number that should be selected, could be sent to the command by passing a parameter to it.

In the Window we can create a binding to the command, so it receives notifications when a button is clicked, and we can then select the new page in the ListBox, which causes the animation to run.

I have written some code that demonstrates this, and just adds a little to what you have already:

view1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstTry.view1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstTry"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="view1" />

        <!-- Button fires command with the value 1 as next pageindex --> 
        <Button Name="show2" Content="show second xaml" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150"
                Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SlideToPage}" CommandParameter="1"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

view2.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstTry.view2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstTry"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightCoral">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="view2"/>

        <!-- Button fires command with the value 2 as next pageindex -->
        <Button Name="show3" Content="show third xaml" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150"
                Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SlideToPage}" CommandParameter="2 </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

view3.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstTry.view3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstTry"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightGreen">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="view3"/>

        <!-- Button fires command with the value 0 as next pageindex -->
        <Button Name="show1" Content="show first xaml" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150"
                Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SlideToPage}" CommandParameter="0"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FirstTry.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstTry"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <!-- Make the window listen for the SlideToPage command -->
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.SlideToPage}"
                        CanExecute="SlideToPage_CanExecute"
                        Executed="SlideToPage_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="views">
            <x:XData>
                <Views xmlns="">
                    <View Title="View1">
                        <Page Source="view1.xaml"/> 
                    </View>
                    <View Title="View2">
                        <Page Source="view2.xaml"/>
                    </View>
                    <View Title="View3">
                        <Page Source="view3.xaml"/>
                    </View>
                </Views>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>

        <Storyboard x:Key="slideLeftToRight"  
                    TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                    AccelerationRatio=".4"
                    DecelerationRatio=".4">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="viewer" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="300" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bordervisual" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="0" To="-300"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="slideRightToLeft" 
                    TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                    AccelerationRatio=".4"
                    DecelerationRatio=".4">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="viewer" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="-300" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bordervisual" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="0" To="300"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <VisualBrush x:Key="VisualBrush1" Visual="{Binding ElementName=viewer}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ListBox x:Name="viewList" Height="20" Width="300" SelectedIndex="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource views}, XPath=Views/View}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="@Title"                    
                    SelectionChanged="viewList_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid Width="300" Height="300">
                <Border x:Name="bordervisual" Width="300">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectanglevisual"/>
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>

                <ItemsControl x:Name="viewer" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=viewList}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Page}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame x:Name="frame" Source="{Binding XPath=@Source}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private static int oldSelectedIndex = 0;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public RenderTargetBitmap RenderBitmap(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        double topLeft = 0;
        double topRight = 0;
        int width = (int)element.ActualWidth;
        int height = (int)element.ActualHeight;
        double dpiX = 96; // this is the magic number
        double dpiY = 96; // this is the magic number

        PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
        VisualBrush elementBrush = new VisualBrush(element);
        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen();

        dc.DrawRectangle(elementBrush, null, new Rect(topLeft, topRight, width, height));
        dc.Close();

        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, pixelFormat);

        bitmap.Render(visual);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private void viewList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlElement root = (XmlElement)viewer.DataContext;
        XmlNodeList xnl = root.SelectNodes("Page");

        if (viewer.ActualHeight > 0 && viewer.ActualWidth > 0)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = RenderBitmap(viewer);
            rectanglevisual.Fill = new ImageBrush(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
        }

        viewer.ItemsSource = xnl;

        if (oldSelectedIndex < viewList.SelectedIndex)
        {
            viewer.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.Resources["slideLeftToRight"]);
        }
        else
        {
            viewer.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.Resources["slideRightToLeft"]);
        }

        oldSelectedIndex = viewList.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void SlideToPage_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //The command can always be executed
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void SlideToPage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //When the command is executed, we find the new pagenumber passed as a parameter
        //and switch the selected item of the ListBox, so the animation will run.
        int pagenumber = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(e.Parameter.ToString(), out pagenumber))
        {
            viewList.SelectedIndex = pagenumber;
        }
    } 
}
```

Commands.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace FirstTry
{
    public static class Commands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedCommand SlideToPage = new RoutedCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me resolve this issue. What about highlighting the listview when the button is clicked just like how it would highlight when viewList_SelectionChanged is selected?

Comment: No problem. I'm happy it solved your issue. If you call "viewList.Focus();" after "viewList.SelectedIndex = pagenumber;" it will select the ListBox and highlight it. That could probably be used I guess.

Comment: Magnificient! Thank you so very much.